# Make Visual Studio IntelliSense autocomplete words by capital letters

Tags: autocomplete, monodevelop, intellisense, completion

Is there a way to make intellisense autocomplete words by capital letters. I got used to way monodevelop autocompletes code,for instance typing SerFi would automatically display SerializeField,but in Visual Studio 2015 it doesn't work that way.

So, my question is if there is option that allows intellisense to do that.

Comment: why not keep using monodevelop instead? :)